# Installing an Angular library from git

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I'm following [this article](https://github.com/t-palmer/example-ng6-lib) to build my shared angular library to use in my other projects. My library structure is like [this repo](https://github.com/t-palmer/example-ng6-lib). I'm trying to find a way to install it as a git dependency in my other projects without publishing it. When I do `npm install mylib@git+ssh://git@github.com/path/to/my/lib` it only copies the source files to my node_modules folder under the library name. I have tried adding a postinstall script which simply does `npm run package` but that fails with the following error:

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
ERROR: Could not resolve './lib/example-ng6-lib.module.ts' from 
dist/example-ng6-lib/esm2015/public-api.js
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not resolve './lib/example-ng6-lib.module' from 
dist/example-ng6-lib/esm2015/public-api.js
See "/private/var/folders/gk/hkq8xkz12q94_s_tbrsjtkbw0000gn/T/ng-BI3VoC/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The interesting part is I can build my library as a stand-alone project by `npm run package` when I'm adding components to it and it builds fine(I can npm-link it from the consumer project and use it, it's all good).
What am I missing?

Comment: I think if you are installing from git you have to go to node_modules/your_lib/ and run npm install. I am not quite sure could you try that once?

Comment: already tried that, the same error!

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I think it is related to node_module path.  @Wildhammer have you solve the issue?

Comment: No, I gave up and started using a private npm registry.